# How to get rid of header in Pivot Control ? Win10

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a pivot control, I want to completely get rid of the header part, but no matter what I do, the header takes up around 50 pnt, I set the height for pivotheaderITem to 0, Auto, Margin and padding to 0 , VerticalAlignment to center or top, but nothing worked.

Comment: How will you switch items without the headers if you use a mouse?

Comment: I have a listbox as the header that it is items are bound to PivotItems

Comment: What do you get from the ListBox that you don't from the headers?

Comment: 1) I don't like the sliding transition of the headers when you move from one to the other. 2) it is easier to style the listBox the way I want it than styling header of the pivot control (I think)

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but I think restyling the headers should be easier and perform better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I would advice not to remove the header completely (because keyboard/mouse users will have a harder time navigating this can be done this way:

Create a new empty header template for your pivot:

```
<Pivot.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="EmptyHeaderTemplate">
        <Grid />
    </DataTemplate>
</Pivot.Resources>
<Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
      <StaticResource ResourceKey="EmptyHeaderTemplate" />
</Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

This will result in an empty header but it will leave an empty area above your pivot item. to remove that you have to create a new template for your pivot and change a few things:

remove the

```
<ContentControl x:Name="TitleContentControl"/>
```

then after that make the itemspresenter take 2 rows and start at row 0 so it takes up the row that was used by the header.

```
<ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.RowSpan="2">
```

I've created a full pivot with no header in this gist on GitHub as a example:
https://gist.github.com/Geertvdc/e02a77ac2adca71a6b3e